# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'audio_session' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

when trying to run my flutter project I am getting the following error message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUE3O.png)

Answer (score 1):

Need to show more of the code, apparently it's just cache, try running

```
flutter clean
```

and also delete the **Podfile.lock** and run comand

```
pod install
```

inside the ios folder

Comment: I did what was asked and it didn't work